# Creating a table view using SQL?

Tags: sql, table, syntax, sql-view

I'm trying to create a table view using SQL to join a table and a feature class together. When I try to create the view, I get an error saying there is an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'. I've double checked my syntax with other examples and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I've attached the short script below:

```
CREATE VIEW OpDash_points AS SELECT
 P.OBJECTID,
 P.SITE,
 P.edited_names,
 P.Field12,
 P.Shape,
 O.Asset,
 O.Project_Name,
 O.Project_Status

 FROM
  tstgis.MPCGIS.Subs_Switches_Telecomm P,
  tstgis.MBRESNAHAN.OpDash_data O

 WHERE
  P.SITE = O.Asset;
```

Comment: maybe a comma after" ..._Telecom P" in the from part ?

Comment: Good eye, though I just fixed it and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Best practice is to use the `JOIN` keyword instead of multiple tables in the `FROM` and a `WHERE` to force the join, but your SQL engine (whatever is might be) might use a different syntax to create views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE VIEW opDash_points as 
Select P.objectid
    , P.site
    , P.edited_names
    , P.Field12
    , P.Shape
    , O.Asset
    , O.Project_Name
    , O.Project_status
FROM tstgis.MPCGIS.Subs_Switches_Telecom P inner join 
        tstgis.NBRESHNAHA.OpDash_data O
            on P.Site = O.Asset
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem ended up being the syntax for the first line. I didn't need the CREATE VIEW syntax, just the SELECT syntax. The script is working now.